# How to get relative depth of XML element using XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to find the relative depth of given XML element from specific element in the given XML file, I tried to use XPATH but I'm not very familiar with XML parsing and I'm not getting the desired result. I need as well to ignore the data elements while counting.

Below is the code that I have written and the sample XML file.
E.g. the depth of `NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier` from `TS837_2000A_Loop` element is 4.

The parent nodes are: `TS837_2000A_Loop < NM1_SubLoop_2 < TS837_2010AA_Loop < NM1_BillingProviderName`
as `NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier` is a child of `NM1_BillingProviderName` and thus the relative depth of `NM1_BillingProviderName` from `TS837_2000A_Loop` is 4 (including `TS837_2000A_Loop`).

```java
package com.xmlexamples;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class XmlParser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("D://sample.xml")));

        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        String expression;      
        expression = "count(NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier/preceding-sibling::TS837_2000A_Loop)+1";                
        Double d = (Double) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);     
        System.out.println("position from  TS837_2000A_Loop " + d);

    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<X12_00501_837_P xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <TS837_2000A_Loop>
        <NM1_SubLoop_2>
            <TS837_2010AA_Loop>
                <NM1_BillingProviderName>
                    <NM103_BillingProviderLastorOrganizationalName>VNA of Cape Cod</NM103_BillingProviderLastorOrganizationalName>
                    <NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier>1487651915</NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier>
                </NM1_BillingProviderName>
                <N3_BillingProviderAddress>
                  <N301_BillingProviderAddressLine>8669 NORTHWEST 36TH ST </N301_BillingProviderAddressLine>
                </N3_BillingProviderAddress>
            </TS837_2010AA_Loop>
        </NM1_SubLoop_2>
    </TS837_2000A_Loop>
</X12_00501_837_P>
```

Comment: A one-liner XML of 4412 characters? More than 4kB? Please take a moment to (1) minimize your example XML to what is needed to understand your question, and (2) layout your example such that it is readable. Please take a minute to read [mcve]. In addition, please explain "relative position". Character position? Node position? Depth?

Answer (score 1):

The pivotal method for getting the depth of any node is by counting its ancestors (which include the parent, the parent of the parent etc):

```
count(NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier/ancestor-or-self::*)
```

This will give you the count up to the root. To get the *relative* count, i.e. from anything other than the root, assuming the names do not overlap, you can do this:

```
count(NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier/ancestor-or-self::*)
- count(NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier/ancestor::TS837_2000A_Loop/ancestor::*)
```

Depending on whether the current, or the base element should be included in the count, use the `ancestor-or-self` or `ancestor` axis.

---

PS: you should probably thank [Pietro Saccardi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749822/pietro-saccardi) for so kindly making your post and your huge (4kB on one line..) sample XML readable.

Comment: @Pietro Saccardi : Thank you very much for making my post readable. I'll keep this in mind while writing my future posts.

Comment: I tried the expressions that you suggested but I'm always getting the count 0. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: I missed // in front of NM109_BillingProviderIdentifier, it's giving me the count now. Let me test for the functionality that I'm developing. Thanks.

Comment: @DaisyD, adding `//` means _"search at any depth in the tree"_. I don't know your full requirements, but if you have multiple elements to search, you probably want to put in a loop and set the focus to the parent element each time you use XPath. If that is the case, you may be better off using XSLT, which is far easier at such tasks (but requires you, well, to learn XSLT...)

Comment: I also need to consider the prior elements except leaf nodes. Eg. For N301_BillingProviderAddressLine, it should consider NM1_BillingProviderName and the count should be 5.

Comment: @DaisyD, they are not ancestors of each other in your example. But if they are, you can use the same approach as above: just subtract the ancestor-count that you do not wish to concern. If you want to know if something is a leaf element (with text, but not with element children), use `xxx[not(child::*)]`, where `xxx` is the node or node set you want to test.

Comment: @DaisyD, as a handy tool, use an XML editor that can select or search by XPath (like oXygen), or use an online tool like http://www.xpathtester.com.